# Django 1.6 - templates for password change/reset

Tags: python, django

I want to use django's password change/reset views so for example for the view

```
django.contrib.auth.views.password_change
```

I need create a template named

```
registration/password_change_form.html
```

the problem is that even though I have this template implemented in my project, django still shows the password-change page of the admin website, the only way I can make django use my template is by renaming it to something different - like registration/password_change_form_1.html and then pass the name

```
url(r'^password/change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    {'template_name': 'registration/password_change_form_1.html',
     'password_change_form': MyPasswordChangeForm},
    name='password_change'),
```

Am I missing something here? why won't django use my template when I use the default name?

Comment: are you using app_directories.Loader in settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think because your app is under `django.contribute.admin` in the `INSTALLED_APP`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by simply putting the 'django.contrib.admin' as the last entry in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Alternatively you can create a `registration` folder in your app with your `password_change_form_1.html` in it, and then it wouldn't matter where you placed `django.contrib.admin`. [This blog post](http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/password-reset.html) does precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically generates the admin template with the default name, so, if you use the admin, you must specify a different template name.

It simply fails to find your template, since it is overiden by the generated one.

Answer (score 0):

Add in settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'registration',
)
```

After

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ...
    "/home/user/templates",
)
```

Add in directory templates "`registration`"
`base.html` that will contain the template and other templates

run in django==1.5