# django auth: password change template customization

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to theme django auth's password change templates to my site.  The problem is that django is seeing the `django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/` versions of the templates instead of my beautifully crafted `myapp/template/registration/password*.html`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048268/django-1-6-templates-for-password-change-reset) poster was told to fiddle with app order in settings.py, which is a bit fragile to my taste.  I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388800/how-do-i-use-the-built-in-password-reset-change-views-with-my-own-templates) poster may have gotten a reasonable answer, but if so, I haven't quite understood it yet.

So what I did was to add a bunch of non-DRY cruft to my `urls.py` file, copied from `auth_urls.py`:

```
# Provide explicit templates where I've provided them, shadowing the URL's
# that registration.backends.defaults.urls will provide.
url(r'^accounts/password/change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    {'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done'),
     'template_name': 'registration/password/change_form.html' },
    name='auth_password_change'),
# ...
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

This works, but saddens me in its repetition.  Surely django encourages something cleaner.  Any pointers?

(Fwiw, django 1.7 and python 3.4.2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this template into your project's `templates` dir and add the following code to the `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

By default `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` is placed before `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` in `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` so project's `templates` directory has precedence over app's `templates`.

Comment: This makes sense, but doesn't work (or I'm doing it wrong). I have not set `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` so I expect the default value.  And `TEMPLATE_DIRS == ()`.  I tried putting `password_change_form.html` in both `myapp/template/registration` and in `myproject/template/registration/`, neither is used.

Comment: Empty `TEMPLATE_DIRS` means that filesystem template loader will not load templates at all.  You have to set this setting (see updated answer). Also note that template directories should be named not `template` but `templates`.

Comment: This works! Thanks. I had misunderstood the behaviour of an empty `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Shouldn't the line more logically be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/templates')`? Only important in that I'd like to follow common practice.

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is already points to your project directory (where `manage.py` lives).

Comment: Aha, I was calling the place where settings.py lives the project directory.